# An ERROR occurred in archiving the artifacts

Tags: java, deployment, jenkins, jar, archive

When I type "build*.jar" into Files to archive filed in Archive the artifacts, the warning red message "build*.jar' doesn't match anything: 'build' exists but not 'build*.jar" appears.

After I ignore it and build, the following ERROR occurred:

```
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "build\*.jar". Configuration error?
ERROR: 'build\*.jar' doesn't match anything: 'build' exists but not 'build\*.jar'
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: kindly try **\build*.jar ... ** points to your workspace

Comment: @DevD just a correction: `**` means `any preceding path`, which may include `$WORKSPACE` but it is not limited to that.

Comment: So if I type 'build/*.jar' the jar file should appear in path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JavaTest\build' ??

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to totally ignore the artifact part, you can select the **Do not fail build if archiving returns nothing** option in Jenkins *Post-build Actions* > *Archive the artifacts* > *Advanced settings*.

Comment: In case like me you were wondering how to do this in DSL, call "archiveArtifacts" with "allowEmptyArchive: true"

Answer (score 0):

Please check if build is a direct folder within your Jenkins Project workspace. For example if , target is a direct folder with your project workspace, target\*.jar will archive all the jars within the target folder. Also, please try clicking on the ? for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answering! But I'd created the "build" folder under my project workspace already before I got this ERROR message :(

Comment: workspace would be cleaned (if checkout happens everytime) a new build starts. so, is this folder created manually by you before the build ? Also, is any code checked out from SCM for each build? Is it a Custom Workspace you are using instead of regular workspace?

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that `\` is escaping `*` and it's looking for literally the file named `build*.jar`.

I assume you are on Windows, hence you are using `\` separator. However most Windows versions support `/`. Try that first:
`build/*.jar`

If that doesn't work, you can try escaping `\` in the first place:
`build\\*.jar`

Comment: I tried several ways (included 'build/*.jar', 'build\\*.jar', '*.jar'...) but none of them worked :(